# Joining Dates to find Active Users

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have created a system to store my active accounts based on the date ranges of their last transaction and the next date that they will be set to be billed on.

I'm selecting the relevant data using the following.

```
SELECT * FROM `ss_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'last_trans_date';
SELECT * FROM `ss_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'next_recurring_date';
```

My objective is Query  all of the accounts that are active between todays date or given date.

An example row for the last_transaction_date

```
umeta_id | user_id | meta_key | meta_value
901891   | 7886    | last_trans_date | 11/4/15
```

An example row for the next_recurring_date

```
umeta_id | user_id | meta_key | meta_value
901291   | 7886    | next_recurring_date | 12/4/15
```

An Active account will be one where todays date is between the last_trans_date and the next_recurring_date.

Comment: Please define what you mean by active?

Comment: Also the second one can't be correct since the meta key value is not the same as the query.

Comment: An Active account will be one where todays date is between the last_trans_date and the next_recurring_date

Comment: Weird my clipboard screwed up, I fixed the data and added the definition of an active account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want last_trans_date to be less than active and next_recurring_date greater than active -- I'd do it like this

```
 SELECT last.user_id
 FROM ss_usermeta as last 
 JOIN ss_usermeta as next on last.user_id = next.user_id
 WHERE last.meta_key = 'last_trans_date' and cast(last.meta_value as date) <= CURDATE()
   and next.meta_key = 'next_recurring_date' and cast(next.meta_value as date) >= CURDATE()
```

Comment: I ran it in SQL pro and got Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous. On a side note is the format that I am storing the dates in acceptable?

Comment: @NicholasKoskowski - and you honestly don't know how to fix that?? Lucky for you I fixed the typo in my answer.

Comment: @NicholasKoskowski - by format do you mean data model? Hard to say without knowing more about how the data is going to be used.  Having a catch all meta table like this is good if meta data type changes a lot (rare) and bad if it is very stable (more common.)

Comment: Simple select statements are all that I have ever written, any tips/resources for getting more acquainted with the finer / more useful points of SQL?

Comment: @NicholasKoskowski - read a bunch of books and work with it for 20 years or so.  That is what I did. :)

Comment: Some of my dates are stored in this format - 7/29/16 (m/d/Y)
And some of the dates are stored in this format 08/11/2016

Does the casting function work appropriately for both of those cases?

Comment: @NicholasKoskowski - I'd expect it to, but I'd have to test it to be sure, haven't used mysql that much.

Comment: I wrote a few things to convert the dates to YYYY-MM-DD formats and now all is well. The query is perfect!